# Fetching value from a nested XML using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to fetch the element amount and its value from the below XML using XPath expression.

```
<donor>
    <beneficiaries>
        <beneficiary>
            <balance>10</balance>
            <additionaData>
                <name>age</name>
                <value>40</value>
            </additionaData>
            <additionaData>
                <name>amount</name>
                <value>1000</value>
            </additionaData>
        </beneficiary>
        <beneficiary>
            <balance>10</balance>
            <additionaData>
                <name>age</name>
                <value>50</value>
            </additionaData>
            <additionaData>
                <name>amount</name>
                <value>4000</value>
            </additionaData>
        </beneficiary>
    </beneficiaries>
</donor>
```

I am able to get the NodeList for beneficiary element but not able to get the content of tag `name` and `value`.

**Update:**

I want to first check if the tag `<name>` in `<additionalData>` is amount if yes fetch the content of `<value>` for all `<beneficiary>`.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
/donor/beneficiaries/beneficiary/additionaData[name='amount']/value
```

will select the two `value` elements associated with "amount" `name` elements:

```
<value>1000</value>
<value>4000</value>
```

This XPath,

```
/donor/beneficiaries/beneficiary[additionaData[name='age']/value = 50]
                    /additionaData[name='amount']/value
```

will select only the "amount" `value` element for the `beneficiary` of age 50:

```
<value>4000</value>
```

---

**Update:**

> i actually want to first check if the tag `<name>` in
>   `<additionalData>` is amount if yes fetch the content of  for
>   all `<beneficiary>`

This XPath,

```
/donor/beneficiaries/beneficiary[additionaData/name='amount']
```

will select all `beneficiary` elements whose `additionaData/name` equals `"amount"`:

```
<beneficiary> 
  <balance>10</balance>  
  <additionaData> 
    <name>age</name>  
    <value>40</value> 
  </additionaData>  
  <additionaData> 
    <name>amount</name>  
    <value>1000</value> 
  </additionaData> 
</beneficiary>

<beneficiary> 
  <balance>10</balance>  
  <additionaData> 
    <name>age</name>  
    <value>50</value> 
  </additionaData>  
  <additionaData> 
    <name>amount</name>  
    <value>4000</value> 
  </additionaData> 
</beneficiary>
```

Comment: thanks .. i actually want to first check if the tag <name> in <additionalData> is amount if yes fetch the content of <value> for all <beneficiary>

Comment: thanks again .. i have never used Xpath before . Now how do i iterate over  the NodeList to get the content of <value> where <name> is amount.

Comment: You're welcome.  Is your latest request not satisfied by the original XPath I offered?  I've already given you several variations.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped, and ask a new question rather than continuously extending this one.  Be sure to be clear to state what you want to select in specific declarative, not procedural, terms.   Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. :-) .. Yes your answer is useful !!! After using the expression (/donor/beneficiaries/beneficiary[additionaData/name='amount']) now i have the NodeList. My requirement is to iterate all the beneficiary node and check the <additionalData> if the <name> is amount fetch the content of <value>

Comment: What you're failing to recognize is that XPath can take you all the way to the node or nodes you want without additional iteration.   I cannot help you further because you refuse to simply state what you wish to select in the end.   Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The below xpath will give values

`//donor/beneficiaries/beneficiary/additionaData/*[name()='name'][.='amount']/following-sibling::*[name()='value']`

```
Element='<value>1000</value>'
Element='<value>4000</value>'
```

If you want to get `age` nodes

modify the above xpath by replacing `amount` with `age`

Comment: thanks .. i have edit the question i need to fetch the content of <value> if the <name> is amount for all beneficiary,

Comment: @Pankaj do you want a java implementation to iterate over nodelist of <name> elements?

Comment: hi svasa .. My requirement is to iterate all the beneficiary node and check the <additionalData> if the <name> is amount fetch the content of <value>